# Git clone displaying errors and marking files as deleted in Windows 10

Tags: windows, git, github, windows-10, git-bash

I am getting the following error when trying to clone a repository with git:

```
Fatal: Unable to checkout working tree
warning: Clone succeeded, but failed checkout.
You can inspect what was checked out with 'git status'
and retry the checkout with 'git checkout -f HEAD'
```

Additionally, the following message appears in several files: 'error: Unable to create file'

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIBr3.png

By using the 'git status' command, I see that many files were marked as deleted [actually the files still exist]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RX36z.png

I used the `git checkout -f HEAD` command as was requested in the first mistake, but the result was the following

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PO8Rf.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, the files in your repository contain question marks (`?`) in their names. The question mark is a special symbol and is not permitted in a file name on Windows.

Afaik, there is no solution for your problem (apart from using a different OS).

However, why the filenames contain question marks? They look like they were scrapped from web by a web spider (on a different OS). The question mark and the fragment after it should not be part of the file names.

Comment: Thanks! I did it and everything is working perfectly! Actually the files have been downloaded by a grabber

Answer (score 5):

Your files has special characters which are not allowed under windows.
This is why you cannot checkout the file names.

**The only way to fix it is to clone the repository on non windows machine and to rename them.**

The following characters are forbidden in file names (Win)

### ***`The following reserved characters:`***

```
< (less than)  
> (greater than)  
: (colon)  
" (double quote)  
/ (forward slash)  
\ (backslash)  
| (vertical bar or pipe)  
? (question mark)  
&#42; (asterisk)
```