# How do I bypass or repair this git clone error?

Tags: javascript, git, github, visual-studio-code

Trying to clone a repo to another local machine, but it keeps failing at a particular point (a folder).

I want to clone a remote  repo I have been working on in my other machine (Linux) into my windows machine (I dual boot) because I ran into some microphone problems in linux and the coding challenge is speech to text. I have tried again and again, but it keeps failing at a folder I titled 'Day 13'

git clone "https://github.com/stealthman22/My-JavaScript30-Challenge.git"

As always I expected a smooth cloning so i can begin working, but here is what I keep getting

C:\Users\user\Documents>git clone "https://github.com/stealthman22/My-JavaScript30-Challenge.git"

```
Cloning into 'My-JavaScript30-Challenge'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 157, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (157/157), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (140/140), done. Receiving objects: 
68% (107/remote: Total 157 (delta 36), reused 132 (delta 14), pack-reused
Receiving objects:  71% (112/157), 45.15 MiB | 118.00 KiB/s
Receiving objects: 100% (157/157), 45.16 MiB | 69.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (36/36), done. fatal: cannot create directory
  at 'Day 13: Slide in on scroll': Invalid argument
warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.
  You can inspect what was checked out with 'git status'
  and retry the checkout with 'git checkout -f HEAD'
```

Comment: A Windows folder or file name cannot contain the `:` character. You need to rename it on your Linux box, push the change, and then try cloning on the Windows box.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git clone displaying errors and marking files as deleted in Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36827671/git-clone-displaying-errors-and-marking-files-as-deleted-in-windows-10)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+warning%3A+Clone+succeeded%2C+but+checkout+failed

Comment: @AustinMullins I will try this right away just got back online. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Windows do not allow the usage of `:` or `\` in the filename as they are reserved keywords for windows.

In your case `:` needs to be removed from the file name and it should work fine.

Comment: Thank you very much I never knew stuff like this, But well  we learn everyday. Any other special character I should beware of?